# How to run a shell script from an AppleScript?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I am using a Mac running OSX Yosemite v.10.10.5.

When I try to run my shell script from my AppleScript, I get the following error message:

Error message at AppleScript Script Editor

```
error "sh: /Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh: Permission denied" number 126
```

myShellScript.sh

```
cd /Users/myusername/Git/myproject/
git remote remove origin
```

myAppleScript.applescript

```
do shell script "/Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shell script is probably missing the execute permission (`+x`). Add it with the shell command `chmod a+x myShellScript.sh` or prepend the shell script with the shell executable name, e.g.:

```
do shell script "bash /Users/path/to/file/myShellScript.sh"
```

Comment: You should also add a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`) as the first line of the script.